# How to load scripts in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB version 3.0 and I want to run script.js on database

Problem I have find is that mongo is not seeing my file script.js.

What I have done step by step:

1. I have installed MongoDB in directory MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\
2. I have put script.js inside \bin directory
3. I want to do is run script.js using load() method
4. I have got an error

   load("script.js")
       2016-10-09T22:17:17.557+0200 E -        file [script.js] doesn't exist
       2016-10-09T22:17:17.558+0200 E QUERY    Error: error loading js file: script.js
           at (shell):1:1

Probably I have put script.js in wrong place but where I should put it?
Next step is I'm using mlab and I want to load my script to the online server, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any magic that would make a \bin directory relevant, but assuming that your script is located in /bin, you just need to call out the full path when you do the load from within the mongoshell

```
load('/bin/script.js');
```

If your script is located off your home directory it will be like

```
load('/Users/yourname/script.js');
```

See the docs for load:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/

Ditto for how you run it on "the server".  Its not so much running on the server, but in the shell that you are running.  If the shell is connected to a particular server, the effects of the script will be on the server but the script itself executes in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

For windows try:
load('c:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\prova.js')

Comment: load('c:\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.0\\bin\\script.js')

Comment: Here's a hint because this is your first answer, please use `edit` function to append more information on your original answer **instead of adding a comment**.

Answer (score 0):

load("C:\\Data\\Mongo\\M001\\loadMovieDetailsDataset\\loadMovieDetailsDataset.js")

Double \ does the trick. I was receiving similar error as my install path was not set and the file res

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the name of the .js file. In my case, the error was coming because the folder name and the file name were the same.